# WinHTTP getElementsByTagName() only shows opening tag for "section"

Tags: vba, autohotkey, windows-7-x64, winhttp, winhttprequest

Using AhtuHotkey 2.0 Beta1 (i assume VBA script as well) `getElementsByTagName()` only shows opening tag for HTML5 tags `section` and `nav` however works with all other HTML4 tags.

AutoHotkey Code

```
HTMLObj := ComObject("HTMLfile")
HTMLObj.write(HTML)

DOMObj := HTMLFileObj.getElementsByTagName("section") 

msgbox DOMObj[0].outerHTML
```

following will return just opening tag `<section class=mysection>` i think it simply does not know how to handle HTML5 tags. Is there solution, i am on Windows 7 x64 Service Pack 1

Comment: You know, you could give some feedback to my answer. Does it work? Does it not work? Any errors? Any comments at all? Setting up a bounty and then abandoning the question is kind of strange.

Comment: Pardon, i got locked out of this account. Thanks for help perhaps you ask admin to mark it as solution.

Answer (score 0):

Old versions of IE('s HTML parser) treat unknown elements as *inline* elements by default. That means the parser auto-closes them as soon the next known block element is encountered.

Try this (a bare-bones version of the much more comprehensive https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv):

```
html5shim =
(
<script>
  document.createElement('header');
  document.createElement('section');
  document.createElement('main');
  document.createElement('article');
  document.createElement('aside');
  document.createElement('nav');
  document.createElement('footer');
</script>
)

HTMLObj := ComObject("HTMLfile")
HTMLObj.write(html5shim)
HTMLObj.write(HTML)

DOMObj := HTMLFileObj.getElementsByTagName("section") 

msgbox DOMObj[0].outerHTML
```

An alternative way would be to add CSS that declares these elements as block elements:

```
<style type="text/css">
  header, section, main, article, aside, nav, footer { display: block; }
</script>
```